# Max size of UNIQUE index in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a max size of a `UNIQUE` index in MySQL?
I have six dimensions in my index, which leads to a massive index.
Is there a cardinality limit to `UNIQUE` index?

I am getting weird unexplained errors and wonder if there is a limit from the `UNIQUE`.
Could it come from a uniqueness limit?
Here is what it looks like (I also don't understand why the cardinality of the last three columns does not increase).

```
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| table |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | column_1      | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | column_2      | A         |       91948 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | column_3      | A         |      924889 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table |          0 | PRIMARY  |            4 | column_4      | A         |    15723114 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table |          0 | PRIMARY  |            5 | column_5      | A         |    15723114 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| table |          0 | PRIMARY  |            6 | column_6      | A         |    15723114 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: You have six unique constraints on a single table?! That could be an indication there's something wrong about the design ;-)

Comment: How many rows does your table currently have? Is it MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: Yes, agreed. I will fix that by enforcing uniqueness elsewhere. However, it raised a point that I am curious about about index max size.

Comment: This isn't 6 unique constraints.  It is one constraint that spans 6 columns.  I'm not sure enforcing uniqueness elsewhere is the answer.  The database is the appropriate place to do it.  Maybe if you post your table definition we could get a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to aggregate logs with six dimensions. Since the whole process is quite long with a bunch of cron scripts (syslogs -> hadoop -> hive (to aggregate by dimension) -> sqoop -> mysql), I want to make sure I don't add the same line twice, hence the 6-column uniqueness. All values are `INT`, `TINYINT` or `FLOAT` so I am pretty far from the limits explained by @svidgen.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**For InnoDB tables**, the limit is 3072 bytes across all indexed columns, presumably taking only the first 767 bytes of each column.

> An index key for a single-column index can be up to 767 bytes. The
>   same length limit applies to any index key prefix. See Section
>   13.1.13, “CREATE INDEX Syntax”.
>
> The InnoDB internal maximum key length is 3500 bytes, but MySQL itself
>   restricts this to 3072 bytes. This limit applies to the length of the
>   combined index key in a multi-column index.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-restrictions.html

So, based strictly on the documentation, I'd say you could have up to 1000 columns in your index (the max number of columns on an InnoDB table), provided that the average size of each is 3 bytes or less.

**For MyISAM tables**, it's the lesser of 16 columns or 1000 bytes.

> The maximum number of columns per index is 16.
>
> The maximum key length is 1000 bytes. This can also be changed by
>   changing the source and recompiling. For the case of a key longer than
>   250 bytes, a larger key block size than the default of 1024 bytes is
>   used.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

Comment: It actually says "Arbitrary length UNIQUE constraints"

Comment: @Tom Interesting ... I'd be interested for a fuller explanation of what that means. In most contexts, arbitrary doesn't generally mean "with disregard for the limits" but rather "any value of whim within the limits."

Comment: Nowadays InnoDB also limits to 16 columns: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-limits.html.