# How many maximum possible indexes we can create in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, database

Is there any Maximum limit in MySQL table, that we can only create a fix amount of indexes in a table?

What is the Maximum possible number of index be created in a table?

Comment: First check official docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Comment: If you have any further questions after checking the docs, probably best to direct them to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted, as it's a legit question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The maximum number of indexes per table and the maximum index length is defined per storage engine. See [Chapter 15, Alternative Storage Engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engines.html). All storage engines support at least 16 indexes per table and a total index length of at least 256 bytes. Most storage engines have higher limits.

From the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html).

Answer (score -1):

@Jonast92 answer nails it.
Length per index is also important (more so for unique indexes).

I would also consider referencing this question's answer too:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16568369/1804013

However, a better question perhaps would be; w*hat's the maximum amount of suggested indexes to have?*

As too many indexes are usually an indication that there's something wrong about the table design. Also, it's worth considering that too many indexes will slow down data manipulation.

**An idea for index discovery:**

- WHERE clauses (including JOIN conditions on equal columns)
- GROUP BY
- ORDER BY

Comment: I have a doubt that having index on group by clause will have a huge impact on performance.